# module 'avro.schema' has no attribute 'parse'

Tags: python, parsing, avro

i am new to python and i was trying to write a simple code for converting a text file to avro. i am getting this error that module not found. I could clearly see in the schema.py file that the parse module exists. I will appreciate if someone could help me understand what i may be doing wrong.

```
import avro.schema, csv, codecs
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter


def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
# csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
csv_reader = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
                        dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
for row in csv_reader:
    # decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
    yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
for line in unicode_csv_data:
    yield line.encode('utf-8')

schema = avro.schema.parse(open('C:/test/test.avsc', "rb").read())
```

I am using Python 3.5.2, avro-python3-1.8.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 52):

You got the avro code sample from their [tutorial](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedpython.html), but unfortunately it's not updated for `avro-python3`.

Instead of:

```
schema = avro.schema.parse(open('file.avsc', "rb").read())
```

You need to read the file in text mode, and use the `Parse()` method:

```
schema = avro.schema.Parse(open('file.avsc', "r").read())
```

Comment: 2.5 years, still nobody updated that documentation error. Awesome.

Comment: Awesome! I agree. How active it is.

Comment: And still at this point they haven't added language version constraints to their pypi packages. So if you accidentally install avro instead of avro-python3 you will get the python2 version installed without complaint.